# How to convert MySQL datetime value to google chart api datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, google-visualization

I am trying to convert a value from a datetime field in a MySQL database to a value I can pass on to a Google chart datetime field.

For example a MySQL value: `2012-03-05 17:03:56`.

Google Chart Api link: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

I want to pass this into a column defined like this: `data.addColumn('datetime', 't');`

I want to send it into a row as such: `data.addRow([date_value]);`

I'm not sure how to convert between the two. So what I am asking is **How do I convert MySQL datetime value to a google chart api datetime value?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's just using the standard javascript Date object. Easier method would be to get a `unix_timestamp(yourdatefield)` out of MySQL, which gives you seconds-since-the-epoch.

Javascript's date object accepts milliseconds-since-the-epoch as one initializer value, so:

```
data.addRow(new Date(<?php echo ($seconds_from_db) ?>000));
                                                     ^^^--- 3 extra zeroes to make it a millisecond value
```

Comment: Change your answer so it prints `new Date(<?php echo ($seconds_from_db) ?>000)`, thanks