# Google Chart Api make use of datetime value

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-api, google-visualization

Hello I want in  my chart to display the datetime, I made some search over the stack and I found similaer problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572052/how-to-convert-mysql-datetime-value-to-google-chart-api-datetime) one but I could not understand how to fix that.

The part of the code that i believe i should change is the below..

```
<?php

$DB_NAME = 'project';


$DB_HOST = 'localhost';


$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = 'smogi';

include_once 'header.php';

$view = ($_GET['view']);
$username2 =$_SESSION['username'];
$firstDate= $_POST['firstdatepicker']; 
$lastDate= $_POST['lastdatepicker'];
$typeValue = ($_POST['typeValue']);
$startHour = ($_POST['startHour']);
$firstMin = ($_POST['firstMin']);
$lastHour = ($_POST['lastHour']);
$lastMin = ($_POST['lastMin']);

$firstTime = $startHour.':'.$firstMin.':00';
$lastTime = $lastHour.':'.$lastMin.':00';

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','smogi','project');

  /* Establish the database connection */
  $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

 $sql="SELECT sensorValue,datetime FROM sensors WHERE username='$view' AND datetime BETWEEN '$firstDate''$firstTime' AND '$lastDate''$lastTime' AND typeValue='$typeValue' ORDER BY datetime DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);




  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.

    array('label' => 'Date Time', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Sensor Value', 'type' => 'number')

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // The following line will be used to slice the  chart

      $temp[] = array('v' => 'Date('.date('Y',strtotime($r['datetime'])).','.(date('n',strtotime($r['datetime'])) - 1).','.date('d',strtotime($r['datetime'])).',0,0,0)'); 

      // Values of the each slice

      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['sensorValue']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;


?>


<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
          hAxis: {title: 'Date & Time'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Sensor Values'},
           title: 'Sensor Data',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 900,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My chart right now look like this ...

[image]

and what i want is instead of 1000,2000...5000 to display the datetime from the data that I am displaying.

My database table that contains the datetime is the below...

[image]

Can you help me please??? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following code:

```
<?php
 $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.

    array('label' => 'Date Time', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Sensor Value', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => array('html' => 'true')),
);

$result = array(
    array('datetime' => '2015-04-25 00:00:00', 'sensorValue' => 5),
    array('datetime' => '2015-04-25 14:30:00', 'sensorValue' => 10),
    array('datetime' => '2015-04-26 02:10:10', 'sensorValue' => 15),
    array('datetime' => '2015-04-26 12:10:10', 'sensorValue' => 17),
    array('datetime' => '2015-04-27 03:45:23', 'sensorValue' => 25),
    array('datetime' => '2015-04-28 15:34:00', 'sensorValue' => 4),
);

    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // The following line will be used to slice the chart

      $temp[] = array('v' => 'Date('.date('Y',strtotime($r['datetime'])).',' . 
                                     (date('n',strtotime($r['datetime'])) - 1).','.
                                     date('d',strtotime($r['datetime'])).','.
                                     date('H',strtotime($r['datetime'])).','.
                                     date('i',strtotime($r['datetime'])).','.
                                     date('s',strtotime($r['datetime'])).')'); 

      // Values of the each slice

      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['sensorValue']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => 'This is a <b>custom</b> tooltip. Insert your data as you like: On the 25th of April, 2015 the sensor value was: <b>5</b>');
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;
// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>


  <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
            'modules':[{
              'name':'visualization',
              'version':'1',
              'packages':['corechart']
            }]
          }"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          tooltip: {isHtml: true}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

so I changed:

1. `array('label' => 'Date Time', 'type' => 'number')` to `array('label' => 'Date Time', 'type' => 'date')`
2. formed the date with `'Date(date("Y"),date("n") - 1,date("d"),0,0,0)'` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379124/sending-json-dates-to-google-charts-api-from-perl)

Here is the result with html in tooltip:

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you want custom tooltips, [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content) is the doc for it. See the updated code above, you need to make three changes to customize tooltips:

1. add the "virtual" column to the list of columns (with role = tooltip):

   `array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => array('html' => 'true')),`
2. add the value for the column in the loop:

   `$temp[] = array('v' => 'This is a <b>custom</b> tooltip. Insert your data as you like: On the 25th of April, 2015 the sensor value was: <b>5</b>');`
3. and let jsapi know that the content is html:

   ```
   var options = {
     ...
     tooltip: {isHtml: true}
   };
   ```

**UPDATE**

In order to customize horizontal axis values, you need to look at [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#axesgridlinesticks) first. Just add `hAxis` object (and its `format`) to the chart options object:

```
    var options = {
      ...
      hAxis: {
        format: 'yyyy-M-d'
      }
    };
```

and you'll see something like:

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for your time but I want it to be as a scatter chart :-/

Comment: What about time (hours,minutes,seconds)? If you want check the updated code

Comment: I updated my answer with the time. Sorry, I hardcoded the time/date values, not in the mood to create test mysql table and insert the values there. Hope you understand the idea and the main thing with the Date() constructor return in JSON data

Comment: Yes thank you, I looked for similar solution but couldn't make it work.
Just one last thing and look at it only if you want , Can we increase the size of the box (http://prntscr.com/6zaa6o) and make it display also the time?

Comment: I think this is the line of code that we need to change `array('label' => 'Date Time', 'type' => 'date'),`

Comment: If i change it to `array('label' => '', 'type' => 'datetime'),` it changes my horizontal line (http://prntscr.com/6zagr4) :-/

Comment: Formatting axis and pop up box is a bit more complicated.  I'll try to look tomorrow

Comment: How I should change this `$temp[] = array('v' => 'On the '.DateTime.' the sensor value was: <b>'.sensorValue.'</b>');` In order to take the datetime and the sensor value?

Comment: just use the date and time as text as you'd inject it into a text or html. Again, this is just text/html, it is not interpreted by JSAPI

Comment: you mean something like that ` $temp[] = array('v' => 'On the '.$DateTime.' the sensor value was: <b>'.$sensorValue.'</b>');`    ???

Again thank you for your time :)

Comment: can you take a look please IF you have time ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974481/remove-double-dates-in-haxis-label-google-chart-api)  Thank you :)